# Docker can't expose mesos port 5050

Tags: docker, mesos

I have a mesos container running, the container has the port mapping `0.0.0.0:32772->5050/tcp`.
If I run `docker exec CONTAINER_ID "curl 0.0.0.0:5050`, I can see the thing I want. However, I can't access `HOST_IP:32772`. I've tried to run nginx in the same container and I can connect to the nginx server in host, so I think it's mesos configuration problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you on Linux directly, or using boot2docker?

Comment: You should tell us your `docker run ...` command settings...

Comment: @VonC I run it on Linux. The problem is I use port forwarding. Thank Tobi for pointing out that I should use host mode!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're running your Mesos Master(s) from a Docker container. You should use host networking instead of bridge networking.

The [settings](https://github.com/tobilg/coreos-mesos-cluster/blob/master/user-data#L86) work at least for me:

```
docker run \
    --name=mesos_master \
    --net=host \
    -e MESOS_IP={YOUR_HOST_IP} \
    -e MESOS_HOSTNAME={YOUR_HOST_IP} \
    -e MESOS_CLUSTER=mesos-cluster \
    -e MESOS_ZK=zk://{YOUR_ZK_SERVERS}/mesos \
    -e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos/master \
    -e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/mesos/master \
    -e MESOS_QUORUM=2 \
    mesosphere/mesos-master:0.27.1-2.0.226.ubuntu1404
```